wrong license displayed in maven site

Include details about your goal

I have a custom license in my project.
When generating the project website using mvn site, I hope to see the correct license displayed under target/site/licenses.html

Describe expected results

After the run of mvn site, I wish to see my custom license under target/site/licenses.html

Describe actual results

After the run of mvn site, I see this license, instead of my custom license:
Project Licenses
Apache License, Version 2.0
                                 Apache License
                           Version 2.0, January 2004
                        http://www.apache.org/licenses/

   TERMS AND CONDITIONS FOR USE, REPRODUCTION, AND DISTRIBUTION




Describe what I tried:

In the root folder of my project, I have this custom license:
Custom License

Copyright (c) 2024, John Smith

Some custom clauses:
[truncated]

Please note, it is definitely not a Apache license
Therefore, while doing mvn site, at the license generation page, I am hoping to see the correct license for my project (not the licenses of the projects I depend on, but my own project).
Please see the "Typically the licenses listed for the project are that of the project itself, and not of dependencies."
However, it seems 1) maven is not able to pick this custom license and display it on site webpage, 2) is displaying a default apache license, which is not the license of my project.

Show some code:

Here is the content of the pom:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>licenseone</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>licenseone</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>



Question:

How do I display a custom license in the site generated by maven?
(please note, this is not a question about software licensing, but a technical maven question on how to display license properly)

Can you show the pom.xml? Do you have a <licensing> tag there?

ah, maybe this is the root cause. I attached the pom file. Is there a way to "link" my custom license, or "indicate" my custom license? (upvoted your comment)

See https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Licenses.

Do you know how do I link my whole custom license file, which is located at the base of my project, to this  block?

Is it really a custom license? The one you have shown in your question looks pretty standard to me.

Yes, I pasted one that looks standard, our company built a custom one on top of it. I m just interested to know how to link it to the pom as you suggested. But you are correct, let me edit the question to reflect that

Can you add that custom license to the <licenses> section? Specifically, add the <name> of the custom license as well as a <url> pointing to the license as a text file and a custom <comment> if you want to. Does that change anything?

pom.xml
... 
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>licenseone</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <!-- Add this -->
    <licenses>
          <license>
             <name>My License</name>
             <url>MY-LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
             <distribution>manual</distribution>
             <comments>My A business-friendly OSS license</comments>
          </license>
    </licenses> 
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

...



put MY-LICENSE-2.0.txt in your project root directory (same directory as pom.xml)
